# Request source code from internal page using jquery same domain

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the source of an internal domain page can have it basically cloned into a js file.

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I have attempted to start what the code might look like.

I realize the var source is probably where I go wrong as that will not function correctly.

Hopefully someone can try to debug my code.

Thanks!

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      // make request to site
    var request = "http://mysite.com/page.html";
      // get the dom from the html layer
    var source = $(request+'html').html();
      // output to the dom the source of the request
    $('html').append(source);
    });
```

Would something like this make more sense?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var create = $('html').load('http://mysite.com/page.html');
document.write(create);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do a simple jQuery .load call?

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

You should load the URL in this way:-

```
$("#result").load("/SivaCharan/CmJuk/ #sidebar");​
```

Here:

- `#result` - It is the div with the id as result.
- `#sidebar` - sidebar is the div id. This will be load on to the result div.

In your case, you are passing full url which will not work.

You should write this way:-

```
$('MENTIONYOURRESULTID').load('/page.html MENTIONYOURDIVID');
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/CmJuk/1/)**